# Mouse Scrolling - Middle Click

Tags: mouse

I'm a linux newbie, and I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 (I think?) on my laptop today.

The one thing that is puzzling me is my inability to be able to scroll through webpages/documents by clicking the middle mouse button and then moving the mouse up and down like Windows. There seems to be no quick way to scroll through long webpages.

I've googled this answer a lot, and haven't found anything of any use. Either the solution has been disabling middle button which I don't want to do, or it is extremely complex and goes way over my head at the moment.

So is there a simple solution to be able to scroll through webpages quickly by clicking my middle mouse wheel like I've been used to doing for years?

Thanks in advance
-G

Comment: Middle click is used differently in linux. It is used for pasting the selected text.

Comment: Okay I understand that is the default usage, but for me I thought Linux was meant to be really customisable, and therefore thought I would be able to change this somehow?

Comment: The scrolling that is implemented in some Windows drivers is not implemented in Ubuntu.

Comment: Why don't you just rotate the wheel?

Comment: Because it is significantly slower than middle clicking and just moving the mouse down a bit to scroll the entire document. So is there no way to work around this? I used to be able to scroll a 100+ page document in seconds if I liked, now it takes forever or I have to click and drag the bar on the right. Seems like a big step backwards to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, Just have to go in EDIT > PREFERENCES > ADVANCED and check AUTOSCROLLING.

Answer (score 0):

Put about:preferences in the Address bar and scroll down until you get to the browsing section. Check the first option that says Use Autoscrolling.
(Can confirm for FF v81+)