# Middle-mouse click doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: mouse, 20.04, mouse-scroll

I have been using Ubuntu for quite a while now from 16.10 to 20.04 LTS, I wonder why the middle-mouse click for scrolling pages doesn't work as it does in Windows, or if there is a setting that I can tweak to get it to work. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Middle-click has another purpose in Ubuntu and many other Linux distros with a graphical desktop environment. It **pastes** wihat you have marked by high-lighting. This works in most but not all software. See for example [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961175/copy-and-paste-doesnt-work-in-the-terminal/961226#961226). -- But you can press the space bar (on the keyboard) to scroll one page (for example in Firefox).

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Mouse Scrolling - Middle Click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754065/mouse-scrolling-middle-click?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the function you mean is **Autoscroll**. It can be activated in Firefox settings (try searching for 'Auto', the Finnish text translates as "Automatically scroll the page"). It seems that Chrome has an extension for it. I don't use the function very often, and don't know how many other programs have it.

The middle click is used as an alternative copy paste function in unix/linux. That's why it's not commonly used for autoscroll.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're on any Chromium browsers this extension resolves the issue.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan?hl=en-US

Restart the browser after installation!